# Online math tool for equation visualisation

Tags: computer-assisted-proofs

I am looking for a math editor that is able to present equations and relations between them. I am not searching for a traditional Latex / MathML editor (I know about various online services that allow typing in equations in various formats then outputting a pretty picture). I know about [online sage notebook](http://www.sagenb.org), about [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org) and that like. I also know about [Lurch](http://lurch.sourceforge.net/) and Wolfram Alpha (thanks to tp1 below).

What I'm looking for is something like [pearltrees](http://www.pearltrees.com) in interface with pearls being equations and edges indicating the source of the concepts (other equations or axioms). The equations should be editable and each may have an additional page that explains the equation, maybe from external source like Wikipedia.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy5yx.png) is a sample tree with a [direct proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_proof) directly from Wikipedia.

> Consider two even integers x and y. Since they are even, they can be written as x = 2a and y = 2b respectively for integers a and b. Then the sum x + y = 2a + 2b = 2(a + b). From this it is clear x + y has 2 as a factor and therefore is even, so the sum of any two even integers is even.

(can't embed images yet)

Comment: wolfram alpha might work.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Wolfram Alpha is a very interesting tool but this is not what I'm talking about here. What I'm talking about is ... a tree index for the content shown by Wolfram Alpha. :) What Wolfram Alpha presents is suitable for the "side pane" that would be presented when one clicks on a node.

Comment: @TNick would the result you are looking at be something that summarizes the current state of mathematics ... perhaps in a mindmap?

Comment: what I'm asking in this particular question is an user-oriented editor. Any user should be able to "import" definitions (nodes) from other users (as reference/shortcut, not importing the entire content) and build on that (similar to Lurch). So it's not about "current state of mathematics" (but that is an interesting idea on its own). Creating new content from existing content by the software is also outside the scope of this particular question (also interesting to contemplate).

Comment: okay! A small example linking basic equations to each other would help a lot when people come to read this question.

Comment: @VincentTjeng Posted a sample image above as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

#### Trees for some equational proofs

[Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) (which is [Online](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/)) recently added some functionality to find proofs for some equational logic theorems and present them in various ways in both text and a tree.

There are a lot of examples/pictures at [the reference page for `FindEquationalProof`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEquationalProof.html). One particularly striking picture is a tree for a proof that one axiom implies a collection of 3 for [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke#Definition). If $(ab)$ denotes $a\,\operatorname{NAND}\,b$, then the three axioms

1. $((aa)(ab))=a$
2. $(a(ab))=(a(bb))$
3. $(a(a(bc)))=(b(b(ac)))$

all follow from $(((ab)c)(a((ac)a)))=c$. Mathematica proves this in 250 steps with a tree like:
[image: proof tree for NAND logic]

---

#### Trees for many theorems

This doesn't cover equational proofs *yet* because it's only been done for the first 1000 proofs, but [Antony](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/255275/antony) is working on automatically converting [metamath](http://us.metamath.org/mm.html) proofs to trees at [this github repository](https://github.com/Antony74/graphmm). For example, [this page](https://github.com/Antony74/graphmm/blob/master/output/svg/ccase.svg) shows the following tree for [the theorem "ccase"](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/ccase.html), which roughly says that if we have $P\land R\to T$ and $Q\land R\to T$ and $P\land S\to T$ and $Q\land S\to T$, then we can derive $(P\lor Q)\land (R\lor S)\to T$:
[image: tree for ccase]